# Need to extract the sibling child value using regex

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

In the below XML snippet,i need to extract and store in a variable the value of NAME1, when the Parent node is E1 and the element PARVW equals AG.

For the above snippet, the answer shud be: soldtoid =W

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: *"Need to extract the sibling child value using regex"* No, you really don't. Regular expressions are ill-suited for processing XML data, and even if you got something working it would be fragile and likely to break with even the slightest change in the data.

Answer (score 5):

Use an existing XML parser (such as XML::LibXML) rather than writing your own shitty one!

You can access the desired node using the following XPath:

```
//E1EDKA2[PARVW/text()="AG"]/NAME1
```

I think that can be simplified to

```
//E1EDKA2[PARVW="AG"]/NAME1
```

Comment: I need Regex...I am good at xslt myself but its the regex that catches me blindfolded sometimes.

Comment: I'm not writing you a regex-based XML parser

Comment: @SaiKishoreBeeram: Why do you say "I need regex"? Using regexes is completely the wrong way to parse XML.